# Can I install Drupal Commerce as a site in a multi-site architecture, preferably using Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: 7, commerce, multi-sites, installation

Commerce Kickstart comes bundled with the latest version of Drupal and modules necessary for it to operate.

I already have a Drupal install where various sites make up a multi site architecture. Can I use Commerce Kickstart to install a store as one of those sites in that architecture? Note, this would be stand alone. I don't want the default install to be Commerce where there would be an attempt at a multi store setup, I just want one of the sites to be a Drupal Commerce site.

The CK project pages says, "Who should use Commerce Kickstart? Anyone who wants to skip weeks of configuration to build a commerce site on the Drupal Commerce framework."

Certainly I would like to avoid weeks of configuration and setup.

Is this possible? And if so, what's the best workflow to get it installed and the demo store setup?

If this is not possible, please indicate as much, and let me know if it's possible to install Drupal Commerce as a site in a Drupal multi site architecture nonetheless.  If this is the direction I need to go, what would be the folder structure under sites/store.mysite.com? Would I simply follow the directions on the Drupal Commerce project page as if it were an independent installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much research, I've found out the following:

**Can Commerce Kickstart be added to a multi-site installation?**

The answer is **No**.

As Clive pointed out, CK ships with patches to Drupal core, so it's definitely not unmodified.  Additionally, [CK will break if one tries to migrate an already existing, stand alone installation to be one of the sites in an existing multi site setup](https://drupal.org/node/2217545). CK depends on the installation profile to be present to continue to function correctly. Finally, Bojanz, a contributor to the project, [points out](https://drupal.org/comment/8575847#comment-8575847), CK is a distribution and has to stand alone.

**Can Drupal Commerce be added to a multi site installation?**

The answer is **Yes**.

In that same answer above, Bojanz also points out that Drupal Commerce can be added to a multi site architecture. The caveat is that it has to be built out a la cart with modules as needed that make up the Commerce Kickstart distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You want to follow the [Alternatives, Recipes and Issues Documentation for Commerce Kickstart](https://drupal.org/node/1291122).

> You have many options as an advanced sitebuilder:
>
> - Move modules into sites/all/modules or sites/all/modules/contrib:
>     Although installation profiles build with the modules in the profiles
>     directory, many developers want them in sites/all/modules. Before
>     running the installation process, just move the modules from
>     profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules into sites/all/modules with any
>     tool you like. For example, mv profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/*
>     sites/all/modules/
> - Add Commerce Kickstart to an existing Drupal
>     codebase: Visit the releases page, find your release, and download the
>     -no-core.tar.gz or -no-core.zip version of commerce_kickstart and uncompress it into profiles/commerce_kickstart OR drush dl
>     commerce_kickstart. Either of these will include the required modules.
>     NOTE: This does not mean we recommend installing kickstart on an
>     existing site. A big part of kickstart is the installation process,
>     which this will skip and may not even work.
> - Updating the PHP memory
>     limit if necessary: Commerce Kickstart installation involves the
>     installation of 3 major contributed modules all at once on top of
>     Drupal 7 itself, which may cause you to hit your memory limit during
>     installation. If this happens, installation fails, and you will need
>     to drop all tables from your database and reinstall with a higher
>     memory limit (recommended 96M or higher to be safe; decrease as needed
>     afterward).

Comment: Right, I came across that. It seemed that the 2nd option was most applicable. However, it's very vague. Does it mean that it will work if I'm installing into a fresh, vanilla Drupal install, just avoid a mature site? That section is also seems contradictory. The first half seems to support it can be done, and there is even a no-core option for it, but then says "it may not work" but doesn't give any details there or anywhere as to how it may fail. I'm still left with more questions than answers. Why is the install process so important if CK ships with an unmodified Drupal core?

Comment: Finally, that area doesn't mention anything specific to multi site architectures. If I indeed have "many options as an advanced site builder." I would hope somewhere on the web there would more details about those options as those 3 paragraphs seem to be lacking. Any links in the comments to advanced configuration options for commerce are much appreciated.

Comment: You just take the modules in no-core zip and place the whole profile directory into your drupal sitedir profile directory. The page explains it fine. You then try to install your new site using install.php. Its typical Install Profile usage on a multisite drupal install. Create a backup 1st of course. If u want a simpler way devote some of your free time in creating the solution or directions. Drupal is free and community driven.

Comment: @blue928 Kickstart currently has 5 core patches (see PATCHES.txt in the root), certainly not an unmodified Drupal core. You might want to think twice about running it as a multisite with non-Kickstart sites. I haven't tried it or anything but certainly those core patches need looking at in the context of a 'normal' Drupal site at least before going forward

Comment: @Clive Thanks for pointing that out. I also learned in the drupal.org forums that the installation profile cannot be removed after installation as CK's continued functionality relies on it being there. Additionally, bojaz chimed in just now with the verdict: CK cannot be added to multi site, however, building it a la cart is possible. https://drupal.org/node/2217545. For all the reasons above, looks like we have our answer. I'll add  it as an answer and we can clean up the comments.